# correct try-catch output in eclipse but not in cmd

Tags: java, eclipse, error-handling, cmd

I'm driving myself a lil crazy for this..
I am trying to catch the number of arguments inputed from command line when calling the Java program I wrote, in Eclipse I get the correct output but in win cmd I get the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException.
I then used try-catch, again, it works in eclipse but not in win cmd...what am I missing?

if I insert all the arguments it works perfectly from both ends, it's just when I want to get the missing arguments that it doesn't work.

below a simplified version of the code I used:

```
public static PrintWriter outWrite;
public static String[] allInput;

    public static void main(String [] args) {

           // I first tried this

                if(args.length==0){
                    System.out.println("Missing arguments. Please try again");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                if (args.length==1){
                    System.out.println("Missing second argument. Please try again");
                    System.exit(0);
                }


           // and then the try-catch, I leave both of them here so you can see them 

            try{
                myMethod(args[0]);
                String input2 = args[1];
            // here I'm just saving the output of myMethod to the input2
                try {
                    outWrite = new PrintWriter(input2, "UTF-8");
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                System.out.println("Missing arguments. Please try again");
                System.exit(0);
            }
       }
```

I looked at this too [Eclipse gives different output than cmd using runtime exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764250/eclipse-gives-different-output-than-cmd-using-runtime-exec) without success

---EDIT adding command line used and precise error: ----
command line used in win is `java Driver` which should give me message I wrote in the code
instead it gives me the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at myPackage.Driver.main(Driver.java:31)
```

`line 31` in the error corresponds to the first line inside the `main()` method in the snippet above.

in eclipse the `(Driver.java:31)` has another number at is correctly points to the `myMethod(args[0])` line

the correct command line is `java myPackage.Driver fileIn.txt fileOut.txt` which works perfectly from both win cmd and eclipse

any help would be awesome!
thanks :)

Comment: Wat is the command you used on the Windows cmd to call your application? And what are the command-line arguments you set in Eclipse? It is also helpful to see the stack trace of the exception which is thrown.

Comment: @Hoopje - thanks for the reply, I edited the main post by adding command line and error, hope this helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alright, after two days of attempts and headache I found a solution:

the error was due to the fact that Eclipse compiles the .java files while you need to do it with `javac` in win or Mac.

I could not use `javac` in win since it was giving me the `javac is not recognized error` (I just changed PC) and after looking up the post here [javac is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709041/javac-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or), I was able to compile it using:
`javac *.java` in my `src` folder

from there I was finally able to get the correct output from both sides (cmd and eclipse) with the correct error handling messages

I admit I am not totally sure about why I was getting the correct output from cmd as long as I used both arguments, but the solution above worked for me.